# Why does not exist available "Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter" at "Power & Cables - Mac Accessories"?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-appstore, displayport, vga-adapter

For an old MacBook Pro bought in 2012 as:

- MBP 13.3/2.9/2X4GB/750/SD
- Model No: A1278

I have the `Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter`.

Now if in [Power & Cables](https://www.apple.com/shop/mac/accessories/power-cables) page exists available the old [Apple 60W MagSafe Power Adapter (for MacBook and 13-inch MacBook Pro)](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC461LL/A/apple-60w-magsafe-power-adapter-for-macbook-and-13-inch-macbook-pro)

#### Question

- Why does not exist available `Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter` at *Power & Cables - Mac Accessories*?

Comment: Apple isn't obligated to carry accessories for products they sold over a decade ago.  You can find this [Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter](http://radnex.us/star-tech-active-mdp-vga-adapter) almost anywhere.  I recommend getting a quality active adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apple webpage [About the Apple Mini DisplayPort adapters](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204149) references the adaptor, as shown below.

[image]

---

However, when selecting the link [Apple Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB572Z/B/mini-displayport-to-vga-adapter) shown in the above image, I end up at a webpage with the following popup.

[image]

The part number is MB572Z/B, which can currently can be found for sale as new and used by searching the internet.

So evidently, Apple does not show discontinued products on their [Power & Cables](https://www.apple.com/shop/mac/accessories/power-cables) webpages.

Comment: Where did you find the "MB572Z/B" code?

Comment: In the link https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB572Z/B/mini-displayport-to-vga-adapter.